# Regex lookbehind alternative

Tags: regex, irssi

I am looking for regex lookbehind alternative because autodl-irssi doesnt support it.

Here is my current working regex and test string:

https://regex101.com/r/Cg6mPv/1

I think that regex needs the following replacement (mode modifier and positive lookbehind):

```
(?i)(?<=\s|^|\W)
```

Highlights every line containing any of these words (no case sensitive):

```
*update*
*dlc*
*expansion*
*artwork*
*fix*
*keygen*
*goodies*
*guide*
*trainer*
```

Doesnt highlight if line containts a word (no case sensitive):

```
*fitgirl*
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Your pattern is not well-written and thus is not clear. However, it seems like you want to match a word boundary before a word char, so you can replace `(?<=\s|^|\W)` with `\b(?=\w)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the quick answer, I think it works flawlessly!

Comment: If you have further issues with the pattern, please edit the question and let me know via a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<=\s|^|\W)` pattern is basically equal to `(?<=^|\W)` or `(?<!\w)`, a place in string that is either the string start position, or a location immediately preceded with a non-word char (i.e. a char other than a letter, digit or `_`).

Thus, it makes sense to match a word boundary position that is *followed* by a word char instead:

```js
\b(?=\w)
```

This construct is equal to `\m` or `[[:<:]]` *leading* word boundary constructs that are supported  by some (not many) regex flavors and just require a word char to appear immediately to the right of them.